# Stop the current video from playing when the next button is clicked in Drupal 7

Tags: video, drupal, drupal-7, slider

I'm using version drupal 7 to create the  "slideshow" to display the slideshow of the video, each video is embedded in its own content item.

When the user starts to play the video, if the video is still playing, click "Next", the slide will advance to the next slide, but the video of the previous slide will not stop playing (all browsers). Then, the user can click to play the next video, and then two videos will be played at the same time. If the user advances to the next slide, they may start playing the third synchronized video, and so on. When the user clicks "Next" to go to the next slide, I want to stop any video that is currently playing.

Can someone provide some simple code to prevent multiple videos on different slides from playing at the same time?

This is my video HTML code:

```html
<video class="video-test" style="width:96%;padding-left:6%;" controls>
  <source src="./sites/default/files/MyGovUC 2 0.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I have tried to use the below js but doesn't work.

```html
$('.video_test').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  player.pause();
});
```

My front-end result like the below sample picture:

[image: output 1]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `afterChange` event to trigger your handler when the *slide* changes (not the video), so you need to select the slick element. Then in the handler you can just pause all (or only those matching your selector) videos :

```js
$('#<slick_id>').on('afterChange', function() {
  $('.video_test').each(function() {
    this.pause();
  });
});
```

Comment: What means of  #<slick_id>? Where I can get the slick_id?

Comment: LIke what is the meaning of '.video_test' or where did you get it.. This is an example of a jquery selector to get you the slide element, no meaning except it should correspond to the element (via a class, an id or whatever), also it seems you are using slick so I gave this particular example. Now you need to find the HTML id of your slick courousel yourself, nobody can do that for you, but learning jquery basics a bit could help ?